# Indexed views and self join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[AccountQuickFindBen]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
select 
AB.AccountId,
AB.AccountNumber,
AB.Name,
AB.CreatedOn,
AB.CreatedBy,
AB.OwningUser,
AB.Telephone1,
AB.Telephone2,
AB.EMailAddress1,
AEB.New_contact_title,
AEB.New_contact_first_name,
AEB.New_contact_last_name,
AEB.New_regnumbers,
XXowninguser.FullName as OwnerIdName,
XXcreatedby.FullName as CreatedByName,
8 as OwnerIdType
from dbo.AccountBase AB
inner join dbo.AccountExtensionBase AEB ON AB.AccountId = AEB.AccountId
inner join dbo.SystemUserBase XXowninguser on XXowninguser.SystemUserId  = AB.OwningUser
inner join dbo.SystemUserBase XXcreatedby on XXcreatedby.SystemUserId = AB.CreatedBy
```

The problem comes when I try and create an index on it (on AccountId) it's not possible because it says the view contains a self join. I'm assuming this is because i'm joining to the same table twice.

Is there anyway around this?

Thanks

Comment: You could remove the joins and implement the lookup using a user-defined function.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't "index" a *view* anyway. A view *is* its underlying query.

Comment: You can index a view.  The read performance increase comes from persisting the data.

Comment: [Why do you think an index is a good idea for *this* view?](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-wrong-optimizations/#opt5)

Comment: @Mike No, SQL Server supports indexed views, Oracle supports materialized views, etc. However there are a lot of restrictions and an index won't magically make all views go faster.

Comment: Ahhh.... interesting.  I wonder how an indexed view would *work?*  "Persisting the data?"  Sounds like some interesting reading that I need to do.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Yes, it makes a physical copy of the data. It has to be maintained, just like normal indexes, and the benefits are usually only when you're using aggregations. This is because the gain is not in "speeding up the join" it is in reducing the amount of data you have to read. If you read 10,000 Account rows from the base tables or from a persisted copy of the base tables, there is no real difference.

Comment: Why, *"thank you, Aaron!"* That's certainly something that I had overlooked "in all these years." It *does* sound like a most-interesting feature.

Answer (score 0):

No, there’s no good way around this.

One thing you can do is create one indexed view with just one of the joins to dbo.SystemUserBase, then create another non-indexed view that does the other join, ie from the first view to dbo.SystemUserBase again. You get most but not all of the performance gain, and you can put WITH NOEXPAND in the second view’s SQL, thereby avoiding having to include it in all queries that select from the view.